# Error when trying to issue data manipulation statements with executeUpdate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, exception

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'address', 'userName', 'password') VALUES ('nu' at line 1

I am getting above error when I'm running my gui to input data into the table.

I'm using the code below

```
class registerInterface extends JFrame {

    static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String USERNAME = "root";
    static final String PASSWORD = "root";
    private JTextField jtfFname, jtfLname, jtfAddress1, jtfAddress2, jtfCity, jtfZipcode, jtfState, jtfUsername, jtfPassword, jtfPassConfirm, jtfEmail, jtfdtype;
    private JButton exitButton, backButton, clearButton, submitButton;
    private JMenuItem jmiBack, jmiClear, jmiSubmit, jmiExit, jmiHelp, jmiAbout;
    String first, last, email, address, username, password, dtype;
    
       // launch the application
    public void Create() {

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO person ('firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'address', 'userName', 'password') "
                    + "VALUES ('" + first + "', '" + last + "', '" + email + "', '" + address + "', '" + username + "', '" + password + ")");
            statement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    registerInterface() {
        //create menu bar
        JMenuBar regMenuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //set menu bar to the applet
        setJMenuBar(regMenuBar);

        //add menu "operation" to menu bar
        JMenu optionsMenu = new JMenu("Options");
        optionsMenu.setMnemonic('O');
        regMenuBar.add(optionsMenu);

        //add menu "help"
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        helpMenu.setMnemonic('H');
        helpMenu.add(jmiAbout = new JMenuItem("About", 'A'));
        regMenuBar.add(helpMenu);

        //add menu items with mnemonics to menu "options"
        optionsMenu.add(jmiSubmit = new JMenuItem("Submit", 'S'));
        optionsMenu.add(jmiClear = new JMenuItem("Clear", 'C'));
        optionsMenu.add(jmiBack = new JMenuItem("Back", 'B'));
        optionsMenu.addSeparator();
        optionsMenu.add(jmiExit = new JMenuItem("Exit", 'E'));

        //panel p1 to holds text fields
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(11, 11));
        p1.add(new JLabel("First Name: "));
        p1.add(jtfFname = new JTextField(15));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Last Name: "));
        p1.add(jtfLname = new JTextField(15));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Street Address 1: "));
        p1.add(jtfAddress1 = new JTextField(15));
        
        p1.add(new JLabel("E-mail Address: "));
        p1.add(jtfEmail = new JTextField(15));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Username: "));
        p1.add(jtfUsername = new JTextField(15));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Password: "));
        p1.add(jtfPassword = new JPasswordField(15));
        //p1.add(new JLabel("jtfdtype: "));
        //p1.add(jtfdtype = new JTextField(15));


        //panel p2 to holds buttons
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p2.add(exitButton = new JButton("Exit"));
        p2.add(backButton = new JButton("Back"));
        p2.add(clearButton = new JButton("Clear"));
        p2.add(submitButton = new JButton("Submit"));

        //Panel with image??????

        //add panels to frame
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        panel.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        //listners for exit menuitem and button
        jmiExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        //listner for about menuitem
        jmiAbout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "This is the registration panel"
                        + "\n Assignment for University",
                        "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });


        //listners for clear menuitem and button
        jmiClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtfFname.setText("");
                jtfLname.setText("");
                jtfAddress1.setText("");
                
                
                jtfEmail.setText("");
                jtfUsername.setText("");
                jtfPassword.setText("");
            }
        });

        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtfFname.setText("");
                jtfLname.setText("");
                jtfAddress1.setText("");
  
               
                jtfEmail.setText("");
                jtfUsername.setText("");
                jtfPassword.setText("");
            }
        });

        //action listeners for back buttons and redister menuitem
        backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
                welcome.setVisible(true);
                welcome.setSize(500, 500);
                welcome.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                registerInterface.this.dispose();
                registerInterface.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        jmiBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
                welcome.setVisible(true);
                welcome.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                registerInterface.this.dispose();
                registerInterface.this.setVisible(false);

            }
        });

        //action listeners for Login in button and menu item
        submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String a = jtfFname.getText();
                String b = jtfLname.getText();
                String c = jtfEmail.getText();
                String d = jtfAddress1.getText();
                String u = jtfUsername.getText();
                String f = jtfPassword.getText();
               // String g = jtfdtype.getText();
                
              
                Create();
            }
        });
    }
}

 and this is the table im using

CREATE TABLE PERSON (
    ID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR (50),
    city VARCHAR (20),
    userName VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    dtype VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE KEY (email)
            );
```

Comment: Get rid of the single quotes around firstName, lastName and so on.

Comment: I think David means, get rid of the single quotes around the column names ;)

Comment: Missing apostrophe next to the password value: `'" + password + ")");`

Comment: Hey that has fixed it, but when it manipulates the table, the values inserted are all null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way to see the query before execution in order to figure out the error:

```
    public void Create(String first, String last, String email, String address, String username, String password) {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO person(firstName, lastName, email, address, userName, password) VALUES(")
                .append("'").append(first).append("',")
                .append("'").append(last).append("',")
                .append("'").append(email).append("',")
                .append("'").append(address).append("',")
                .append("'").append(username).append("',")
                .append("'").append(password).append("'")
                .append(")");

            System.out.println( query.toString());

            statement = conn.prepareStatement( query.toString() );
            statement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }

            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }

        }
    }
```

you can change your submitButton function like this:

```
    //action listeners for Login in button and menu item
    submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String fName = jtfFname.getText();
            String lName = jtfLname.getText();
            String email = jtfEmail.getText();
            String address = jtfAddress1.getText();
            String username = jtfUsername.getText();
            String password = jtfPassword.getText();

            Create(fName , lName, email, address, username, password);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey cheers how can I implement this with my gui to get the jtextfields?

Comment: modified as per your requirement

Comment: Yes that looks correct, I'm just trying to add this code to mine.. not sure how.

Comment: remove the definition: String first, last, email, address, username, password; replace your submitButton action with provided one and your create function implementation with provided one... let me make it complete for you

Comment: Seems to working fine just having trouble with the the `statement.close();`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use prepared statement in this way. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Use prepared statement in this way:

```
    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(
          "INSERT INTO person (firstName, lastName, email, address, userName, password) "
          + "VALUES (? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        statement.setString( 1, first);
        statement.setString( 2, last );
        statement.setString( 3, email );
        statement.setString( 4, address );
        statement.setString( 5, username );
        statement.setString( 6, password );
        statement.executeUpdate();
```

this also prevents from silly mistakes like missing apostrophes.
Here is a tutorial `how to use PreparedStatement` : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Cheers for this, how can I make it so my gui can implement this.

Comment: Just copy and paste this example into your code, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You missing `'` at last of your statement. Your statement should like:

```
 PreparedStatement statement = 
 conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO person ('firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 
                      'address', 'userName', 'password') "
                     + "VALUES ('" + first + "', '" + last + "', '" + email + "',
        '" + address + "', '" + username + "', '" + password + "')");
```